# Authentication error while connecting to remote elastic search using kibana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6, aws-elasticsearch

Elastic search is running in remote aws server and I have configured the end point link in local kibana it was showing authentication error. Image corresponding to the error is attached below[image]

And the corresponding log message is :

[error][status][plugin:elasticsearch@6.4.2] Status changed from yellow to red - Authorization Exception

Comment: Please post your kibana config here

Comment: elasticsearch.url: "http://search-xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"

# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
kibana.index: ".kibana"

Comment: The change that I have made is  adding eastic search remote url to the confg file

Comment: Are you able to access Elasticsearch endpoint from your local machine ? Please post the output of `https://search-xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_cluster/health` accessing from your local machine

Comment: I have posted in the response on the other question